# Problems with AC3D, missing libXmu.so.6

Tags: 13.10

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 (64bit), and am trying to run `AC3D`.  When I try to run AC3D (from `cli`) I receive the error that I am missing `libXmu_.so.6`.  Where is it, or where can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on **AC3D** you may need to have the 32bit version of the library which you can install using the command `sudo apt-get install libxmu6:i386`